# Automatically changing typed syntax into the current language

Tags: vscode-extensions, porting

There are so many minor syntaxes changes like `.push()` vs `.append()` and `.count()` vs `.length()` vs `.size()` vs `len()` that I'm having trouble remembering all the small changes between each language. Is there something, like a VSCode extension, that will automatically autocorrect to the chosen language?

For example if I type `array.push()` in python it will autocorrect to `array.append()` or if I do `array.slice(1,2)` it will autocorrect to `array[1:2]`|

Comment: If there were something like that you would never really learn a language and would constantly write wrong code. How can you every be sure what you wrote works as intended? If you don't want to learn a language then don't use it.